# proper use of time_is_before_jiffies()

Tags: timer, linux-kernel

My Linux device driver has some obstinate logic which twiddles with some hardware and then waits for a signal to appear.  The seemingly proper way is:

```
            ulong timeout, waitcnt = 0;
            ...

            /* 2.  Establish programming mode */

            gpio_bit_write (MPP_CFG_PROGRAM, 0);  /* assert */
            udelay (3);     /* one microsecond should be long enough */
            gpio_bit_write (MPP_CFG_PROGRAM, 1);  /* de-assert */

            /* 3.  Wait for the FPGA to initialize. */
            /* 100 ms timeout should be nearly 100 times too long */

            timeout = jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(100);

            while (gpio_bit_read (MPP_CFG_INIT) == 0  &&
                   time_is_before_jiffies (timeout))
                      ++waitcnt;   /* do nothing */

            if (!time_is_before_jiffies (timeout))  /* timed out? */
            {
                  /* timeout error */
            }
```

This *always* exercises the "timeout error" path and doesn't increment `waitcnt` at all.  Perhaps I don't understand the meaning of `time_is_before_jiffies()`, or it is broken.  When I replace it with the much more understandable direct comparison of `jiffies`:

```
            while (gpio_bit_read (MPP_CFG_INIT) == 0  &&
                   jiffies <= timeout)
                      ++waitcnt;   /* do nothing */
```

It works just fine:  it loops for awhile (1600 µS), sees the INIT bit come on, and then proceeds without triggering a timeout error.

The [comment for `time_is_before_jiffies()` is](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/jiffies.h#L150):

```
/* time_is_before_jiffies(a) return true if a is before jiffies */
#define time_is_before_jiffies(a) time_after(jiffies, a)
```

As the sense of the comparison seemed nonsensically backward, I replaced both with `time_is_after_jiffies()`, but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?  Maybe I should replace use of this confusing macro with the straightforward `jiffies <= timeout` logic, though that seems less portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jiffies <= timeout` comparison does not work when the jiffies are wrapping around, so you must use it.

The condition you want to use can be described as "has not yet timed out".
This means that the current time (`jiffies`) has not yet reached the timeout time (`timeout`), i.e., `jiffies` is *before* the variable you are comparing it to, which means that your variable is *after* `jiffies`.
(All the `time_is_` functions have `jiffies` on the *right* side of the comparison.)

So you have to use `timer_is_after_jiffies()` in the `while` loop.

(And the `<=` implies that you actually want to use `time_is_after_eq_jiffies()`.)

The timeout check should be better done by reading the GPIO bit, because it would be a shame if your code times out although it got the signal right at the end.
Furthermore, busy-looping for a hundred milliseconds is extremly evil; you should release the CPU if you don't need it:

```c
unsigned long timeout = jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(100);
bool ok = false;
for (;;) {
    ok = gpio_bit_read(MPP_CFG_INIT) != 0;
    if (ok || time_is_before_eq_jiffies(timeout))
       break;
    /* you should do msleep(...) or cond_resched() here, if possible */
}
if (!ok)  /* timed out? */
    ...
```

(This loop uses `time_is_before_eq_jiffies()` because the condition is reversed.)

Comment: The loop should be 1.6 ms so I haven't worried about hanging the CPU.  This operation is performed once during system initialization and then very rarely again—if ever.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it.  Both functions had issues:  the `timer_is_before_jiffies()` having misleading (or confusing) meaning, and `gpio_bit_read()` overlooking the Armada 370's peculiar architecture which uses different addresses for reading vs. writing.  Wow!